# TS: class private property undefined but private static is not. Why?

Tags: typescript

I was trying to access a private property from a method that is called by the parent class.

This doesn't work. I suppose that is because it's the parent class calling and `private value` belongs to the child class, so it's invisible;

```js
abstract class Block {
  constructor (x: number, y: number) {
    this.x = x
    this.y = y
    this.build()
  }

  protected abstract build(): void
}

class Square extends Block {
  private value:number = 1

  protected build() {
    console.log('do stuff with x & y & value', this.value) // this.value = undefined
  }
}

new Square(10, 10)
```

Since in my use-case `value` is a constant, I tried some other things and finally came up with this:

```js
class Square extends Block {
  private static readonly value:number = 1

  protected build() {
    console.log('do stuff with x & y & value', Square.value) // works
  }
}
```

This works. And I'm glad.

But in my mind, the *private* keyword should work the same. And since `build()` is still called by the parent class, I don't understand why I can access it now.

Can someone explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On `new Square(10, 10)` you implicit call the constructor. You may do not notice it, but `Square` have one as well. If you transpile your typescript code to javascript, you will get something like:

```
class Square extends Block {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.value = 1;
    }
```

As you see here, `Block#constructor` is invoked first, which call `build` when `this.value` is not yet set. Aftert `build` is executed, `value` is *then* set to 1.

Comment: Great, thanks for the explanation. So what would be the recommended practise here: use the static property, or run `build()` separately on the instance?